# Laravel Auth inside object there is an email

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, guard

I have created an auth guard of customers using sanctum .But i am using mongo db . the error that arises is unauthorized when I am trying to log in. as email is not in collection .its inside an object can anyone suggest me a solution for this?

Comment: If you want to convert your object to a Laravel Collection, you can simply place the object inside a collect() method and it will convert it

Comment: Nope My query is not that .i want to perform auth login using email and password but in customer collection email is located inside an object